# Check if a key exists in play.api.libs.json.Json

Tags: json, scala, collections, playframework, scala-collections

`contains` like functionality for `play.api.libs.json.Json`

```
val data=Map("id" -> "240190", "password" -> "password","email" -> "email@domain.com")

data.contains("email")//true


val info=Json.obj("id" -> "240190", "password" -> "password","email" -> "email@domain.com")
```

now how to check `info` contains `email` or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
info.keys.contains("email")
```

The `.keys` gives you back a `Set` with the key values and then you can call the `contains` method, I'm not sure there's a more direct way to do it.

Comment: `keys` yields a `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, It was a typo.

Answer (score 8):

```
(info \ "email").asOpt[String].isEmpty
```

as asOpt would return Optional, we can have isEmpty simple check, this would do what we want.

Comment: Some explanation might help future visitors.

Comment: @errhunter thankq!

as asOpt would return Optional, we can have isEmpty simple check, this would do what we want.

Comment: You can edit your answer to add the explanation, instead of writing it as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
(info \ "email").asOpt[String] match {
  case Some(data) => println("here is the value for the key email represented by variable data" + data)
  case None => println("email key is not found") 
}
```

Comment: This won't work when you do things like `.asOpt[Boolean]`, which will always give you a Some(false) when the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`(info \ "email").asOpt[String]` works only if email is a string. If email is an object, `(info \ "email").asOpt[String]` will be None.
An alternative is to match `(info \ "email").toOption` to `Some` or `None`.